# How to display divs inline in this example

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display 3 `div`s inline and have tried using a container `div` and setting it to use `inline-block` however this didn't work. Am I missing something obvious with this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tablebox" id="box1" style="display: inline-block; border: solid 1px black; width:500px; height:200px;">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Form</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Fill this in</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic">
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Option 2</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic">
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="example">
        <div style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapping">
            <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
            <div class="boxer" id="box1" style="border: solid 1px black; width:150px; height:400px;">
                <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
                <p><span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;">Sort these</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="box" id="box2" style="border: solid 1px black; width:1000px; height:400px;">
                <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your tags are **all over the place**.

Comment: Which divs are you trying to make inline exactly?

Comment: how about float:left?

Comment: I can't count 3 divs with a parent. only 2 divs with a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this that you want?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="tablebox" id="box1" style="display: inline-block; border: solid 1px black; width:500px; height:200px;">
 <form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Form</legend>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Fill this in</label>
     <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Option 2</label>
     <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
<div id="example">
 <div style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;">
            </span>
 </div>
 <div id="wrapping">
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;">
            </span>
  <div class="boxer" id="box1" style="border: solid 1px black; width:150px; height:400px;">
   <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;">
                </span>
   <p><span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;">
                Sort these</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2" style="border: solid 1px black; width:1000px; height:400px;">
   <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;">
                </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I put the two `select` in a row and gave them 6 columns. You can change that to what fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what "3" divs you are talking about, but here is my proposed solution. You can check more about "flex" on google, "display: flex" can be a real saver!

```css
.form-group {
  padding: 5px;
}

#inner_wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tablebox" id="box1" style="border: solid 1px black; width:500px; height:200px;">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Form</legend>
              <div id="inner_wrapper">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Fill this in</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic">
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Option 2</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic">
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="example">
        <div style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapping">
            <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
            <div class="boxer" id="box1" style="border: solid 1px black; width:150px; height:400px;">
                <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
                <p><span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;">Sort these</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="box" id="box2" style="border: solid 1px black; width:1000px; height:400px;">
                <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; margin-left: 10px;"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

use table tag and give each div in each td ...

Comment: Sounds like it should work, don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13876640)

Comment: @worldofjr How does it "not answer the question" if the OP said he implemented this and it worked fine? Whether it's a **good** answer or not is another story (thus the downvotes). But it *does* answer the question IMO.